# Is it possible to see full ('remote') history when using MercurialEclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I'm using MercurialEclipse 2.1.0 (looks like latest) with Eclipse Indigo.

I can't seem to find a way to see the entire history of a file as available in remote 'central' repository (e.g. like it works with SVN) -- the history only seems to show  up to the revision that I currently have in the workspace (in other words in e.g. Synchronize view (in workspace mode) I can see that there are 'incoming' changes in file but 'Show History' wouldn't show me anything about these changes).

Even if I 'Pull' (without 'Update') and check file history it still seems to stop at the current revision.

Anything I can do?

Is there any way

Answer (score 1):

With MercurialEclipse the Synchronize view works best with the "Mercurial Changesets" model. Switching to that will show all of the incoming changesets (be sure the "All branches" button is pressed).

For the 2nd item, having pulled all the changesets, you can see all history if you press the up arrow button in the history view once. This will show all history for the folder that contains the file.

Comment: You're correct regarding the folder history -- it seems to show all history even if you're not updated.

But is this functionality unavailable to files?

And even more importantly -- I prefer not to do pull without update as then I seem to lose track of the stuff that is not fully 'up to date'. If viewing remote history is completely unavailable -- is there at least some indication for projects that are not updated to the 'head'?